# $g$ is monomorphism and $M\cong N\oplus\left(M/g(N)\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M,N$ be two $R$-modules, $f\in Hom_{R}\left(M,N\right)$ and $g\in Hom_{R}\left(N,M\right)$ with the property that $f(M)=N$ and
>   $fg=Id_{N}$. Prove that $g$ is monomorphism and $M\cong N\oplus\left(M/g(N)\right)$.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's a general fact that if $fg$ is injective, so is $g$; it has nothing to do with modules.

Comment: How about the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part follows at once from [split short sequences' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma): look at

$$0\longrightarrow N\stackrel g\longrightarrow M\stackrel\pi\longrightarrow M/g(N)\longrightarrow 0$$

Prove the above is an exact sequence (i.e., $\;g\;$ is one-to-one, $\;\pi\;$ is onto and $\;\text{Im}\,g=\ker\pi\;$ , with $\;\pi\;$ the canonical projection).

Well now, the existence of $\;f\;$ and $\;fg=\text{Id}_N\;$ is *exactly* what is needed to show this sequence splits and we're done!